# WebSphere MQ, how to unlock a channel?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to setup websphere mq in my local machine.
After creating the queue manager, local queue and channel I removed user verification (setup this param CHCKCLNT(NONE))

After this i have next error: The Channel is being blocked from adress '127.0.0.1' since the active channel values have been converted to a user identifier, which must be blocked. Active channel values: 'MCAUSER(MUSR_MQADMIN) CLNTUSER() ADDRESS(DESKTOP-PGP5RVE)'

what do I need to do in this case?

Comment: Define CHLAUTH rules prevent MQ admin users from connecting to SVRCONN channels.  I would suggest you connect as a non-MQ admin user.  There are many posts on SO that discuss this same subject.  I re-tagged your question to the [ibm-mq] tag.

Comment: trying to define CHLAUTH this command: DISPLAY CHLAUTH('CHANNEL1') MATCH(RUNCHECK) ADDRESS('127.0.0.1') QMNAME('queue.manager.1') , get error AMQ9502: The requested action is not applicable to this type of channel.

Comment: This command helped me SET CHLAUTH('CHANNEL1') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) ACTION(REPLACE) USERLIST('nobody')

Comment: As I previously said I would recommend you connect as a non-MQ admin user.  What you have done is turned of security and then allowed any user to connect to the channel now anyone with network access to your queue manager has full access.  Even if this is a non-production development or test server it is better to configure things like you would in production so that you know what to expect.